# Getting a custom post type via json_encode

Tags: php, json, wordpress

I am trying to get all my post data and output it via Json (instance filtering) but I notice that in the Json output there are missing fields i.e. my custom post types:

```
$args = array( 'post_type' => 'job_feed', 'posts_per_page' => -1 );
$loop = new WP_Query( $args ); 
echo json_encode($loop->get_posts());
```

Im wondering how I include them?

Here is a sample of the data:

```
{"ID":19,"post_author":"1","post_date":"2017-10-03 09:32:42","post_date_gmt":"2017-10-03 08:32:42","post_content":"","post_title":"Casual Mail Sorter","post_excerpt":"","post_status":"publish","comment_status":"closed","ping_status":"closed","post_password":"","post_name":"casual-mail-sorter","to_ping":"","pinged":"","post_modified":"2017-10-03 09:32:42","post_modified_gmt":"2017-10-03 08:32:42","post_content_filtered":"","post_parent":0,"guid":"http:\/\/localhost\/Angard\/?post_type=job_feed&p=19","menu_order":0,"post_type":"job_feed","post_mime_type":"","comment_count":"0","filter":"raw"}
```

I am missing a field I created called `regions`

Here is a `var_dump`

`{ ["ID"]=> int(19) ["post_author"]=> string(1) "1" ["post_date"]=> string(19) "2017-10-03 09:32:42" ["post_date_gmt"]=> string(19) "2017-10-03 08:32:42" ["post_content"]=> string(0) "" ["post_title"]=> string(18) "Casual Mail Sorter" ["post_excerpt"]=> string(0) "" ["post_status"]=> string(7) "publish" ["comment_status"]=> string(6) "closed" ["ping_status"]=> string(6) "closed" ["post_password"]=> string(0) "" ["post_name"]=> string(18) "casual-mail-sorter" ["to_ping"]=> string(0) "" ["pinged"]=> string(0) "" ["post_modified"]=> string(19) "2017-10-03 09:32:42" ["post_modified_gmt"]=> string(19) "2017-10-03 08:32:42" ["post_content_filtered"]=> string(0) "" ["post_parent"]=> int(0) ["guid"]=> string(53) "http://localhost/Angard/?post_type=job_feed&p=19" ["menu_order"]=> int(0) ["post_type"]=> string(8) "job_feed" ["post_mime_type"]=> string(0) "" ["comment_count"]=> string(1) "0" ["filter"]=> string(3) "raw" }`

Comment: can you post your output also?

Comment: @AmrinderSingh there you go Sir

Comment: Okay now please just post var_dump($loop->get_posts())

Comment: @danjbh  I am missing a **field** I created called - in what way did you create the field?

Comment: @AmrinderSingh And again there you go

Comment: @ProEvilz via the ACF plugin

Comment: @danjbh Then it's not *missing*, you just simply aren't trying to get it. Remember, they are technically seperate entires in the DB. You need to query ACF & the posts

Comment: It is not because of the json_output, it is not even found in your var_dump output, regions is missing there also

Comment: Sorry yes, my terms are incorrect. Im ot sure how to include it

Comment: @danjbh Try looking at their step by step basic tutorial that came up as a first result in Google [here](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/query-posts-custom-fields/)